# Material-ui overrides react emotion rules

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app, emotion

In my project I use Material-ui components along with react-emotion.

Let me give you an example that is problematic.
I have this element:

```
<CardHeader title={stat} classes={{ root: statNumber }}/>
```

where

```
const statNumber = css`padding: 0;`
```

this way I get to override the default padding (16px) of CardHeader with 0 that is my intention.

In development mode everything works as expected but in production the padding: 0 rule gets overridden by the default padding 16px.

The reason this happens is that in development mode the styles are added in header dynamically. First come the Material-UI styles and then the emotion styles. Like this:
[image: Development mode]

But in production the styles are laid out the other way around

[image: production mode]

This is the reason styles are overridden in production mode.

Material ui provides an explanation on this
https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order

but with the solution proposed I cannot change the order of emotion and material-ui styles are ordered. I can only change material ui and move it further down

Anyone has an idea how to fix this??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue was resolved by changing the order of rendering the style rules. I created a wrapper that needs to wrap the entire app.

```
import React from 'react'
import { create } from 'jss'
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider'
import { createGenerateClassName, jssPreset } from 'material-ui/styles'

const styleNode = document.createElement('style')
styleNode.id = 'insertion-point-jss'
document.head.insertBefore(styleNode, document.head.firstChild)

// Configure JSS
const jss = create(jssPreset())
jss.options.createGenerateClassName = createGenerateClassName
jss.options.insertionPoint = document.getElementById('insertion-point-jss')

function Provider (props) {
  return <JssProvider jss={jss}>{props.children}</JssProvider>
}

export default Provider
```

The wrapper creates an element as the first child inside head. All material ui styles are instructed to be placed there thus they are first in order and can be overridden by emotion rules that come next.

Comment: Nice find. I wish there was component-level solution rather than an HOC that needs to wrap your app.

Comment: material-ui docs on the subject here https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#react-emotion (See "Note" on CSS injection order)

Comment: @Bob B I think that this will not work because material-ui still places their styles before the case injection point.

Comment: It works. You just need to follow the CSS injection instructions I mentioned in the "Note" portion. One of the options is similar to what you proposed in your answer. I was just including a link to the official docs since they provide other options there as well. https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#css-injection-order

Answer (score 5):

The official documentation now shows a very simple way to do it:

https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order

> By default, the style tags are injected last in the  element of the page. They gain more specificity than any other style tags on your page e.g. CSS modules, styled components.
>
> ### injectFirst
>
> The `StylesProvider` component has an `injectFirst` prop to inject the style tags first in the head (less priority):

```js
import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

<StylesProvider injectFirst>
  {/* Your component tree.
      Styled components can override Material-UI's styles. */}
</StylesProvider>
```